How should I link an event to a curve in anylogic
I wrote this source code in any logic:
double minEco = 0.2; // Minimum value for Maturity2
double maxEco = 0.8; // Maximum value for Maturity2
double k = 7; // Sigmoid function curvature coefficient (larger values mean steeper changes)

// Number of points for the chart
int numPoints = 100;

// Clear previous data from DataSet
Evade2Data.reset();

// Calculate values and add to DataSet
for (int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++) {
    double economicSituationRate = i / (double)(numPoints - 1);

    // Use sigmoid function to calculate cumulative value
    Evade2 = minEco + (maxEco - minEco) / (1 + Math.exp(-k * (economicSituationRate - 0.5)));

    // Add calculated value to DataSet
    Evade2Data.add(economicSituationRate, Evade2);
}

also I wrote the code below for economicSituationRate variable:
// Function parameters
double initialRate = 0.5; // Initial value for economicSituationRate
double increment = 0.05; // Annual increase of 5%
int maxYears = 5; // Number of years for gradual increase

// Calculate the current year from simulation time
int year = (int) time(); // Convert simulation time to an integer representing the year

// Calculate economicSituationRate based on the current year
if (year <= maxYears) {
    // Gradual increase up to the fifth year
    economicSituationRate = initialRate * (1 + increment * year);
} else {
    // Fixed value after the fifth year
    economicSituationRate = initialRate * (1 + increment * maxYears);
}

// Print economicSituationRate for debugging (optional)
System.out.println("Year: " + year + ", Economic Situation Rate: " + economicSituationRate);

When I run the model, it should make the curve point by point but it is static. Help me to solve this problem.
I have been trying for one month but I can't solve it.

Hey, first: pls only use the "anylogic" tag, else you confuse other SOF users :) Second: What do you mean by "should make the curve point by point but it is static". What do you want to achieve and what do you get?
